# retrieve logs from server while performing a "parallel" promise.all( request to the server) (parallel challenge!)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, axios

Arriving with a theory question :)

I have a front that sends (axios) N requests in a Promise.all() with a map function. This works fine. Each time one of the promises is good, I have a little table that gets updated with each request's answer until I get the full table and the array of the answers at the end. ✅

The problem comes when I want to read, at the same time, the logs of the server

So my objective is to run another axios request to my express.js server that will run each 2 seconds to retrieve the logs of the last 2 seconds, this way I could show the logs of what is happening with each answer in real time.

Any ideas of how doing this two tasks in parallel?

In the front I'm using react and the promise.All has this is structure:

```
setIsLoading(true); // setting a flag to know this is running
  
const doAllTheTable = await Promise.all(

   tableData.map(async (lineOfMyTable) => {  
   const answer = await doMyRequest(lineOfMyTable) // my axios.get request
   return updateTableLine(answer) // the functions that update the good line
   })
);

//all promises are good now
setIsLoading(false)
```

So, basically I want to have another loop that runs each 2 seconds while "isLoading" is true to update another part of my front and show the logs meanwhile. But I need both things to happen at the same time!

Thank you for your ideas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than awaiting your `Promise.all` immediately, store a reference to the promise so you can start checking the logs:

```
const doAllTheTablePromise = Promise.all(
   tableData.map(async lineOfMyTable => {  
       const answer = await doMyRequest(lineOfMyTable); // my axios.get request
       return updateTableLine(answer); // the functions that update the good line
   });
);

let cancelled = false;
(async () => {
    while (!cancelled) {
        // Check your logs..
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000)); // 2 second delay
    }
})();

await doAllTheTablePromise;

cancelled = true;
```

Once your `doAllTheTablePromise` has resolved, you can stop checking the logs.

Comment: wow eager to try this! Thanks! will come back once i implement it

Comment: `stopChecking()` will resolve the promise but won't stop the checking. The `while` loop will continue to run.

Comment: @Roamer Yes that's right. I've changed the approach.

Comment: So awesome, it works perfectly! I have to work with the timings as reading the last 1 sec of logs does not exactly get the good logs because of the other timings on the server, but that will be fine tuning. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Must be many ways to write this. Here's one involving a token provided by the caller of two async processes, `foo()` and `bar()`, for communication between them.

```
async function foo(tableData, token) {
    try {
        await Promise.all(tableData.map(async (lineOfMyTable) => {
            const answer = await doMyRequest(lineOfMyTable);
            return updateTableLine(answer);
        }));
        token.setIsLoading = false; // lower flag when all requests are complete
    } catch(error) {
        token.setIsLoading = false; // lower flag if synchronous or asynchronous error occurs
    }
}

async function bar(token) {
    function delay(ms) { // this can be written as inner or outer function, whichever suits.
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(resolve, ms);
        });
    }
    if(token.setIsLoading) {
        let logs = await retrieveLogs();
        // process/display logs here
        await delay(2000);
        return bar(token); // recursive call
    } else {
         return "complete"; // optional
    }
}

async function myCaller() {
    // ... preamble
    let loadingToken = { // passed to foo() and bar() as a means of communication between them.
        'setIsLoading': true // raise flag before calling foo() and bar().
    };
    return Promise.all(foo(tableData, loadingToken), bar(loadingToken));
}
```

EDIT:

Maybe better written like this, with the caller looking after lowering the flag:

```
async function foo(tableData) {
    return Promise.all(tableData.map(async (lineOfMyTable) => {
        return updateTableLine(await doMyRequest(lineOfMyTable));
    }));
}

async function bar(token) {
    function delay(ms) { // this can be written as inner or outer function, whichever suits.
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(resolve, ms);
        });
    }
    if(token.setIsLoading) {
        let logs = await retrieveLogs();
        // process/display logs here
        await delay(2000);
        return bar(token); // recursive call
    } else {
        return "complete"; // optional
    }
}

async function myCaller() {
    // ... preamble
    let loadingToken = { // passed to bar().
        'setIsLoading': true // raise flag before calling foo() and bar().
    };
    return Promise.all(
        foo(tableData).finally(() => { loadingToken.setIsLoading = false }), 
        bar(loadingToken)
    );
}
```